# get gdi+ error on calling wpf dll method from windows form application on c#

Tags: c#, wpf

i've created a wpf class library dll to apply an shader effect to a System.Drawing.Bitmap. A method of this class will be called from a "normal" non wpf windows application async callback method (TCPServer send method). 
The method will give me back a Bitmap and seems to working withou any issues. When i will call the Bitmap.Save(...) method i will get a "generic error in gdi+" error. Can anyone see what i've doing wrong?

The WPF Class Library DLL:

```
  public static System.Drawing.Bitmap ApplyShaderToBitmap(System.Drawing.Bitmap Source, String FilenamePS)
    {

        System.Drawing.Bitmap returnBitmap = null;

        Thread STAThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                returnBitmap=Source;

                double WPF_DPI_X = 96.0;
                double WPF_DPI_Y = 96.0;

                PixelShader ps = new PixelShader();
                ps.UriSource = new Uri(FilenamePS);
                LenseCorrectionEffect lce = new LenseCorrectionEffect(ps);


                //Finally, apply the shader effect to img.
                Image img = new Image();
                img.Stretch = Stretch.None;
                img.Effect = lce;

                Viewbox viewbox;
                viewbox = new Viewbox();
                viewbox.Stretch = Stretch.None;
                viewbox.Child = img;


                img.BeginInit();
                img.Width = Source.Width;
                img.Height = Source.Height;


                BitmapSource xx= BitmapToBitmapSource.ToBitmapSource(Source);

                img.Source = xx;

                img.EndInit();

                viewbox.Measure(new Size(img.Width, img.Height));
                viewbox.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height));
                viewbox.UpdateLayout();


                using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    //PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                    JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();

                    //RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)(img.Width * Source.DpiX / WPF_DPI_X), (int)(img.Height * Source.DpiY / WPF_DPI_Y), Source.DpiX, Source.DpiY, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
                    RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(Convert.ToInt32(img.Width), Convert.ToInt32(img.Height), Convert.ToInt32(WPF_DPI_X), Convert.ToInt32(WPF_DPI_Y), PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
                    bitmap.Render(viewbox);

                    BitmapFrame frame = BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap);
                    encoder.Frames.Add(frame);
                    encoder.Save(outStream);
                    returnBitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(outStream);

                    encoder = null;
                    bitmap = null;
                    frame = null;
                }

                xx = null;
                viewbox = null;
                img = null;
                lce = null;
                ps = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                returnBitmap = null;
            }
        });
        STAThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        STAThread.Start();
        STAThread.Join();

        STAThread = null;

        return returnBitmap;
    } // ApplyShaderToBitmap
```

The Calling from a async callback method:

```
bm = LenseCorrection.Shader.ApplyShaderToBitmap(bm, ShaderFilename);

bm.Save(ms, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
```

Thanks forward

Comment: The Bitmap object has a disposed MemoryStream as its backing store.  Kaboom when you try to do anything with the bitmap, like saving it.  You must remove the *using* keyword.  Do not bother disposing it, there is no point.

Comment: Hi, i've removed the using keyword and now it's woking correctly. Thanks for helping me.